# Xstream incorrectly interpreting a list item as part of another list item

Tags: java, list, xstream

I am trying to read from an XML file using Xstream.  The weird issue I am having is that when I make a list of users, it reads the first user correctly, but **it tries to store the *second* user as a member variable of the *first***!  I have this XML file:

```
<data>
    <users>
        <user>
            <username>test1</username>
            <password>test1</password>
            <firstname>Test</firstname>
            <lastname>One</lastname>
            <email>test1@gmail.com</email>
            <indexedrecords>0</indexedrecords>
        </user>
        <user>
            <username>test2</username>
            <password>test2</password>
            <firstname>Test</firstname>
            <lastname>Two</lastname>
            <email>test2@gmail.com</email>
            <indexedrecords>0</indexedrecords>
        </user>
    </users>
    .... There are other tags here, but they're not causing an issue (yet).
</data>
```

The code for the Xstream reader:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
xstream.addImplicitCollection(Model.class, "users", User.class);

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
Class[] classes = new Class[2];
classes[0] = Model.class;
classes[1] = User.class;
xstream.processAnnotations(classes);

String xml = "";//The XML is really stored here, and it does work correctly
xstream.fromXML(xml);
```

And the classes themselves.  Model:

```
@XStreamAlias("data")
public class Model {
    @XStreamImplicit
    public static List<User> users;
    //Other stuff
}
```

User:

```
@XStreamAlias("user")
public class User implements ModelItem{
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @XStreamAlias("firstname")
    private String firstName;
    @XStreamAlias("lastname")
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    @XStreamAlias("indexedrecords")
    private int recordsIndexed;
}
```

The exeption (pardon the `[java]` - it's being run using ANT):

```
 [java] Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Element user of type shared.model.User is not defined as field in type shared.model.User
 [java] ---- Debugging information ----
 [java] class               : shared.model.User
 [java] required-type       : shared.model.User
 [java] converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
 [java] path                : /data/users/user
 [java] line number         : 19
 [java] class[1]            : indexer.shared.model.Model
 [java] version             : null
 [java] -------------------------------
 [java]     at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.writeValueToImplicitCollection(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:403)
 [java]     at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:334)
 [java]     at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
 [java]     at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
 [java]     at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
 [java]     at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
 [java]     at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
 [java]     at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:322)
 [java]     at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
 [java]     at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
 [java]     at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
 [java]     at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
 [java]     at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
 [java]     at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
 [java]     at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
 [java]     at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1052)
 [java]     at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1036)
 [java]     at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:912)
 [java]     at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:903)
 [java]     at importer.Importer.importXml(Importer.java:77)
 [java]     at importer.Importer.main(Importer.java:45)
```

Why is Xstream trying to store the second `User` as a variable inside the first `User`?

**Answer Edit:**  There were two problems, both addressed in Michael's answer.

1) I was implying an implicit collection (twice!) which I should not have done, since the XML explicitly declares a `users` list.

2) My variables in the `Model` class was static.  It is unclear as to why this caused an error, but it did cause it nevertheless.

Comment: Is that XML example correct? It appears to be attempting to close the opening "users" tag with "/user" (without the 's').

Comment: No, sorry, the real XML has it correct.  I'll update the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@XStreamImplicit` annotation before the user list tells XStream that the XML will not have a tag call users but instead all tags called user should be stored in the users list.

Either remove `users` from the XML or remove `@XStreamImplicit` annotation from the variable declaration.

Additional changes
You also need to remove the call to `xstream.addImplicitCollection(Model.class, "users", User.class);` since that is doing something similar to the `@XStreamImplicit`.

The other problem your encountering after fixing the implicit is caused by the users variable in your Model class being declared static.  Since it is static it is not being treated as part of the serialization.

Comment: The XML is beyond my control - it's created externally.  Removing the @XStreamImplicit causes a new error - `Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$UnknownFieldException: No such field indexer.shared.model.Model.users`.  This confused me, because the name of that list in `Model` is exactly `users`.

Comment: Correction: Removing the `addImplicitCollection` (or removing both) did what I mentioned above.  Removing the `@XStreamImplicit`  throws the same error as described in the problem itself.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.  **The root problems were the implicit collection and the variable being static.**  While it would be better for them to have been static, I can fix it so they are not.  Thanks!  (On a side note, thanks for your correct grammar!)